# Should an Animal be abstract or allow for instantiation to represent a "general" instance?

Tags: object-oriented

After a short discussion in [the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104550/downcasting-in-inheritance) I have come to wonder whether or not a baseclass like `Animal` in the traditional OOP example should be marked as abstract or not.

Personally I believe it should: there is no such thing as an "animal", it is merely a term that groups certain subtypes based on what they are. Any instance of an "animal" should be a subtype, a concrete example.

The comment that followed on this was

> There most certainly is such a thing as an Animal. Or would you insist that Dog be broken down into Affenpinscher, IrishWolfhound, SiberianHusky, EnglishSetter, and 600 other breeds?

which is a fair remark but that is different from the original situation where the hierarchy was

[image]

And there are no subclasses of `Dog` in the first place. Should there have been then yes, `Dog` should be abstract because the tree includes more specific leafs for that specific type.

I can only assume that the reason you wouldn't make it a specific subtype is when you simply don't know it. I would instead add a "default" implementation of a dog to account for this so I can keep the `Dog` class itself abstract so there wouldn't be any ambiguity possible: you are forced to either create a specific dog or indicate that you don't know the type.

Furthermore it also allows you to create `abstract` methods that every dog should implement for themselves because they are dogtype-specific. By using a non-abstract class you can't do this and you'll have to remember to override each method in the subclasses.

[image]

In the above tree I would make `Dog`, `Mammal` and `Animal` abstract and allow the others to be instantiated.

The question boils down to this: **should you be able to instantiate a class that exists to indicate a subspecies or should you defer the creation of such a "general" object to a subtype?**

Comment: Consider that BufferedInputStream is a subclass of FilterInputStream, which is not abstract.  I'm sure there are dozens of such examples in the Java API.

Comment: And understand, of course, that "Animal" and "Dog" are merely dummy names used to illustrate inheritance, similar to the way that "Vehicle", "Car", and "Truck" are often used.

Comment: I believe hiearchies like that don't make any sense from OOP perspective. Primarily because they don't express hieararchy of behaviors.

Comment: Opinions are heavily divided on the question whether non-leaf classes should be abstract or not.

Comment: @Euphoric: or, hierarchy of requirements. Requirements determine the behavior, and the subsets of behaviors required for each type determines the interface, and nested interfaces are grouped into hierarchy. Because requirements come from software specification, one has to be either BDUF (big design up-front), or Agile + XP (be willing to change code to meet changing requirements).

Comment: When you're working with animals you can't really instantiate a class dog, because what would it be? A dog has a race: Doberman for instance. In the real world, where you're programming, you can easily instantiate your TStringList class, work with and but also derive a TStringListWithPictures from it and work with that. To me the animal references just make it harder to think about OO.

Comment: The whole "Hierarchy of Animals" example is such a poorly conceived exercise for an Object Oriented design. There's no way to answer how it should be modeled without knowing just _what_ about the animals is important. In most real programs, it's probably more than enough to just model an "Animal" with its various traits, such as its taxonomy, as class members. If every animal species gets its own class, you'll be stuck deriving a class hierarchy until you go insane.

Answer (score 4):

Think about the scope of your business logic. If your application records sounds made by your pets, you may want to make a difference between dogs and cats; otherwise, when you call `myCat.Bark`, something may go wrong. On the other hand, an Irish wolfhound barks, and a Siberian husky barks as well, making *this* distinction irrelevant.

In this case, `Dog` and `Cat` would be actual classes, and `Animal` will be abstract.

On the other hand, if your application handles different breeds of dogs and cats, the difference between a Siberian husky and an English setter becomes relevant.

Now, `Affenpinscher` and `IrishWolfhound` will be actual classes, while `Animal` or `Dog` would be abstract.

The comment:

> There most certainly is such a thing as an Animal. Or would you insist that Dog be broken down into Affenpinscher, IrishWolfhound, SiberianHusky, EnglishSetter, and 600 other breeds?

doesn't take scope in account. When all I want is to record the sounds of cats and dogs, business-wise, there is no such a thing as an instance of the `Animal` class: it's either a dog or a cat. If it's a dog, his breed doesn't matter; it may be a property of `Dog` class, but certainly not a part of the class hierarchy.

Comment: Huskies don't really bark, but they definitely "talk" a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Unless each subtype adds distinct *behavior*, the differences will present themselves as *attributes* of the various instances, e.g., `breed`, `color`, `weight`, etc. I doubt very much you'll need to model a `TwentyEightPoundBlackIrishWolfhound` as a subclass.

If you're building a Twenty Questions game (Is it an animal, vegetable, or mineral?) a concrete `Animal` class might make sense.